# How to delete VirtualBox networking rule?

Tags: virtualbox

I add a rule:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm "xp" --natpf1 "guestrdp,tcp,127.0.0.1,33890,,3389"
```

I list it:

```
VBoxManage showvminfo "xp" | awk '/NIC/ && /Rule/ {print}'
NIC 1 Rule(0):   name = guestrdp, protocol = tcp, host ip = 127.0.0.1, host port = 33890, guest ip = , guest port = 3389
```

But how can I delete it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The first argument inside the quotes of the rule you created is the rule name. You can delete the rule by name like this:

```
VBoxManage modifyvm xp --natpf1 delete guestrdp
```

To find these kind of things out the fastest place to look is `VBoxManage --help | less`.